# How to make a changing number of squares always fill a parent container in a vue component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm creating a vue component showing a three pane layout consisting of a topbar, a right sidebar and a main content area. In the main content area, I want to draw a matrix of squares. The number of squares changes dynamically and can be between one and 400. All squares should be of the same size, but the squares should change their sizes so that together they fill the space inside the main content area, regardless of the number of squares. E.g. one square should be as big as the main content area, two squares should be as big as possible while fitting side by side, with four squares, each should fill a quarter of the content area and so on.

Reducing it to the essential, I have the following:

```vue
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 900px;">

        <!-- Topbar -->
        <div class="row bg-light" style="height: 15%;">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p>Topbar</p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Main content and sidebar -->
        <div class="row" style="height: 85%;">
            <div class="col-9 border">
                <div class="row bg-info">
                    <div class="card m-1 text-end"
                        style="min-width: 0.5cm; min-height: 0.5cm;" v-for="num in squares" :key="num">
                        <div class="card-body p-1">
                            {{ num }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-3 border">
                <h3>Sidebar</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            squares: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
    },
}
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

Which amounts to this:

[Using bootstrap cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyaqn.png)

I have tried using css grid, which seemed promising at first, but the squares would fill the container only horizontally:

```vue
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid border-danger bg-dark" style="height: 900px;">

        <!-- Topbar -->
        <div class="row bg-light" style="height: 15%;">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p>Topbar</p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Main content and sidebar -->
        <div class="row bg-info">
            <div class="col-9 border">
                <div class="grid">
                    <div v-for="num in squares" :key="num">{{ num }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-3 border">
                <h3>Sidebar</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            squares: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
    },
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.grid > div {
  background: grey;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.grid > div::before {
  content: "";
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
}

</style>
```

Which amounts to this:

[Using css grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC24s.png)

I'm stuck. How can I best achieve having the squares fill the content area?

Comment: try to use `flex` instead of `grid`

Comment: Have a look at [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/poZJqzp) I created some time ago. Maybe it'll give you some ideas. I don't use vue, can't help you with that...